# ASP.NET Calendar control is not displaying February 29th ,when i have removed the option to select year

Tags: asp.net, calendar

I was asked to remove the option of person selcting a birthday year and just need month and date .I have removed the option to select year from Calendar Control using this code

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" TitleFormat="Month">   </asp:Calendar>
```

However now if i check ,the month of February has only 28 days ,which may cause a problem for a person with birthday on February 29th

I have found one way that is to keep selected day as 29th feb ,but was wondering if there is some other way to do it

Comment: Is this the only code you are using? "TitleFormat" only changes how title is displayed, but does not affect dates themselves. Say if you have Feb 2017 selected and Title says "February" you still need to go back to Feb 2016 to see 29th

Comment: Yes ,i used only that line but i guess its wrong to use it the way i did .

Comment: It is not wrong, it is just not going to give you what you want. ASP.NET calendar is somehow limited in customization, it cannot do just "day&month pickup" without year. Checkout other controls though, there are plenty of easy-to-use ones